# How to update one table from another table using Trigger in C#?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I am having a scenario in which I have 1 table (Temp_Enquiries_tbl) that contains user enquiries with TEMP_TICKET_NUMBER and 1 table (Enquiries_tbl) that contains approved enquires. I want to copy the data of temp table in permanent table on 1 condition.
When user will submit the enquiry, it will get track in Temp_Enquiry_tbl table with Temp ID. Administrator of the website check the enquiry and when he will confirm the enquiry (when the status of an enquiry change from pending to approve) then the enquiry should get inserted in Enquiries_tbl with Unique ticket number.
I want to implement this task with the help of trigger. How can i do this?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2008 R2 with Asp.net C#

Comment: A trigger is usually implemented on the database, not in whatever is querying it, so you really want a trigger on your SQL Server database.

Comment: Yes, I want to implement the above scenario using the Trigger. I know the logic but I never use trigger. What I studied is trigger is fired on Insert, Update, Delete event.